# Hide toolbar on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, responsive

I'm working on my responsive website and I'm trying to hide the address bar and toolbar of mobile browsers.
On this picture, you can see which zone I'm trying to hide (red mark)

[image: Example what to hide[1]]

So as I've seen when I scroll on my mobile this automatically disappear.

What I'm trying to do is once the document is ready to do an auto scroll. Something like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#id").offset().top
    }, 2000);
```

This element is practically on the bottom of the website but still don't hide the toolbar of the web browser.

Is there any way to hide it?

**EDIT:** I've to clarify that this is not on my website, i'm trying to hide de footer of practically all browsers, i know that this is not possible beacause is on client side, but i'm trying to do a "trick" to hide it. I know that when i use my mobile i open safari and i navegate there is a footer to open a new tab or close it etc... But when i scroll down on a website this one disappear, so this is what i'm trying to do. Create an automatically scroll down to make it disappear... But this is not actually running

Comment: Just to clarify: this element is not part of your own website but rather part of the webbrowser ui, right?

Comment: @Mathyn True this is not a part of my website, is about web browser, but when i interact on my phone, and i scroll down, this footer disappear, so i'm trying to do the same automatically to hide footer

Comment: @Mathyn Post edited

Comment: @KaSkuLL I don't think you can tell the browser what do to using javascript. Or any language I guess(unless you are developer of that browser).

Comment: I do not know if this is possible but even if it is I would advise against doing this. It breaks the way a user expects their web browser to work leading to a confusing and possibly frustrating experience. Instead think of a way to design your website so this bar is not a problem anymore.

Comment: @ShubhamRajdhar Yes i know, but as i've said when i scrolldown on my mobile (using my finger) this footer disappear (is practically the same on all mobile web browsers) so what i'm trying  to do is an automatically scroll down when open the website to make it disappear. This is actually not working

Comment: @Mathyn Totally agree with you. Just trying to do a hot fix. :(

Comment: @KaSkuLL Oh sorry, my bad. I misunderstood it. I think the disappearance of the bottom menu happens only when the user interacts with the mobile screen, (or the browser).

Comment: Regardless of whether or not it's possible, forcibly trying to remove the user's browser bar seems like a really bad idea. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to solve this would be to use the Fullscreen API as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API).

For example:

```
// Covering all browsers that support this
var docEl = document.documentElement;
var requestFullScreen = docEl.requestFullscreen || docEl.mozRequestFullScreen || docEl.webkitRequestFullScreen || docEl.msRequestFullscreen;
var cancelFullScreen = doc.exitFullscreen || doc.mozCancelFullScreen || doc.webkitExitFullscreen || doc.msExitFullscreen;

// Execute the variable on initalization
requestFullScreen.call(docEl);
```

Answer (score -1):

use Jquery to add a CSS and display it as none

```
if(condition that you want){
$(.'your-menu').css({'display':'none'});
}
```